# How do you fetch multiple pages with UrlFetchApp?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I need to get all the contacts from Moneybird api. But there is a limit 50 or 100 contacts a page.

This is added to the header if there is a next page
https://moneybird.com/api/v2/270942000047355483/contacts.json?page=2; rel="next"

How can i loop over the pages with UrlfetchApp in google apps script? or a better method?

Thanks for your help!

````
function listAllContacts() {
  
  var options = {
    'method': 'GET',
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    'muteHttpExceptions': false,
    'headers': {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + SERVICE.getAccessToken()
    },
  };
  
  var url = 'https://moneybird.com/api/v2/'+ADMIN_ID+'/contacts.json';
  
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
  var headers = response.getAllHeaders();
  var link = headers["Link"];
  // Check if there is a rel='next'? then fetch next page
  
  var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  var resonseCode = JSON.parse(response.getResponseCode());
  console.log(resonseCode);
  console.log(data);
  
  
  return data;
  
}```
````

Comment: Does money bird api return page token?

Comment: From the official document. I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? Unfortunately, I cannot test this script. I apologize for this. So when you tested this and it cannot be used, I apologize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve all pages using the loop from the URL of `https://moneybird.com/api/v2/'+ADMIN_ID+'/contacts.json`.
- The official document says "Pagination" as follows.

  > Endpoints returning a list of entities, are paginated to prevent large responses. To control the pagination, you can use the page and per_page parameters. page determines which page to return (default: 1), per_page controls the amount of entities to return (default: 50, maximum: 100)
  > Each paginated response contains a Link header with information about the previous and next page:

  ```
        Link: <https://moneybird.com/api/v2/contacts.json?page=3>; rel="next",
            <https://moneybird.com/api/v2/contacts.json?page=1>; rel="prev"
  ```

From above situation, I thought that at the last page, `rel="next"` might not be included. Using this, I would like to propose the following modified script.

#### Modified script:

```
function listAllContacts() {
  var options = {
    'method': 'GET',
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    'muteHttpExceptions': false,
    'headers': {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + SERVICE.getAccessToken()
    },
  };
  var url = 'https://moneybird.com/api/v2/'+ADMIN_ID+'/contacts.json';
  
  // I modified below script.
  var results = [];
  do {
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
    var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    results.push(data);
    var resonseCode = JSON.parse(response.getResponseCode());
    console.log(resonseCode);
    console.log(data);
    
    var headers = response.getAllHeaders();
    var link = headers["Link"];
    var checkNextUrl = link.includes("next");
    if (checkNextUrl) url = link.split(";")[0].match(/<(\w.+)>/)[1];
  } while (checkNextUrl);
  return results;
}
```

#### Note:

- Unfortunately, from your question, I couldn't understand about the response values from the API. So in this case, the response values are put to the array of `results`. About this, please modify it for your actual situation.
- From the official document, in order to reduce the number of loop, to use `per_page` to the URL might be useful.
- When my guess was not correct, can you provide the response headers at the last page? By this, I would like to confirm it.

#### Reference:

- [Pagination of Moneybird API](https://developer.moneybird.com/#pagination)