# How to call a function and use it's return value?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am not sure how I can pass params in a function, currently I want to store an access token in one function and then pass the params into another function, is there something I am missing or doing wrong?

```
function access_token()
{
  var token = zauthorization().access_token;

  var header = 
  {
    "Authorization":"Zoho-oauthtoken " + token
  }

  return header
}

function module(access_token)
{

   var options = 
  {
    "method":"get",
    "headers": header
  }
  
  var url = "https://recruit.zoho.com/recruit/v2/CustomModule1"
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options)
  return JSON.parse(res)
}
```

So in short I am not sure how I can pass the header into my next function, I need to have it done that way to go onto the next function, I need to create another function after this which will allow me to access data in a specific module so I can have the counted rows returned, I just need to know how to pass parameters in a new function from another function that can be used.

Comment: Your question is little bit unclear for me. So you need to create a new function to pass headers?

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62824493/7215091) is a good example of Tanaike passing a bunch of params into a urlFetchapp.  He has a lot of answers about using UrlFetchapp.  You can go to top users and the search on his user number and get all of his answers on urlfetchapps and if you read throught them I bet you'll learn a lot. And you might give him a little attribution along the way.  Not that he needs it.

Comment: Have you tried calling the `access_token()` function, since the return is the header you could do a `var header = access_token()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but I think you can do it like this:

Since your first function returns the header

```
function myfunk() {
  var token = zauthorization().access_token;
  var header = { "Authorization": "Zoho-oauthtoken " + token }
  return header;
}

function module() {
  var options = { "method": "get", "headers": myfunk() };
  var url = "https://recruit.zoho.com/recruit/v2/CustomModule1"
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options)
  return JSON.parse(res)
}
```

Or more simply perhaps this:

```
function module() {
  var options = { "method": "get", "headers": { "Authorization": "Zoho-oauthtoken " + zauthorization().access_token } };
  var url = "https://recruit.zoho.com/recruit/v2/CustomModule1"
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options)
  return JSON.parse(res)
}
```

But I'm not familiar with what zauthorization() is so I could be totally off base here.  If so sorry.

Answer (score 2):

It seems a bit simple what I think you are asking, but the only thing I can think is:
You call a function by writing it's name and pass arguments in brackets separated by a comma if there are more.

```
myFunction(parameter1,parameter2,55,'This is a text string passed.')
```

parameter1 and 2 are variables, then a number, then a text string.